# How to fix exception on passing JavaBean as parameter of report?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I need to put some complex(arbitrary, pojo) object to report. I tried to use `parameter` tag for this purposes but it doesn't work. I try to google this but I founded examples with simple parameters types (such as String or Long) or using some datasource, but I think I don't need it just for 1 object.

My pojo is:

```
public class CaseDescription {

private final Long id;
private final String logoPath;
private final String userName;
private final String location;

public CaseDescription(final Long id, final String logoPath, final String userName, final String location) {
    this.id = id;
    this.logoPath = logoPath;
    this.userName = userName;
    this.location = location;
}

public Long getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public String getLogoPath() {
    return this.logoPath;
}

public String getUserName() {
    return this.userName;
}

public String getLocation() {
    return this.location;
}

}
```

and my jrxml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="cool_name" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" orientation="Landscape" columnWidth="535" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="13acf49e-4913-4d1b-bccc-113817ad15d1">
...
<parameter name="caseDescription" class="path.to.case.description.package.CaseDescription" isForPrompting="false"/>
...
<group name="Group1">
    ...
    <textField>
        <reportElement style="SubTitle" stretchType="ContainerBottom" x="0" y="30" width="451" height="29" forecolor="#000000" uuid="4636f2b9-3394-42cd-ac90-e34f582b2272"/>
        <textElement textAlignment="Left">
            <font size="22" isBold="false"/>
        </textElement>
        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Accused : " + $P{caseDescription.userName}]]></textFieldExpression>
    </textField>
    ...
</group>
...
</jasperReport>
```

I try to generate document by following code:

```
final CaseDescription caseDescription = new CaseDescription(1L, "Some", "Gump", "Forrest");
Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>();
parameters.put("caseDescription", caseDescription);
JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(resourceAsStream);
JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, new JREmptyDataSource());
JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, pathForSaving);
```

And I got follow exception:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRValidationException: Report design not valid : 
 1. Parameter not found : caseDescription.userName
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.verifyDesign(JRAbstractCompiler.java:280)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.compileReport(JRAbstractCompiler.java:152)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compile(JasperCompileManager.java:357)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReport(JasperCompileManager.java:617)
```

But if I replace `caseDescription.username` to `caseDescription` than will be used `caseDescription.toString()` for this field. Cahnge such as `caseDescription.getUserName()` also not working. Could anyone to explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: `Cahnge such as caseDescription.getUserName() also not working. Could anyone to explain me what I'm doing wrong?` What does it mean, not working (any exception)? You need to add import (optional) and use getter, like this: `$P{caseDescription}.getUserName()` or `((CaseDescription) $P{caseDescription}).getUserName()` - for `<parameter name="caseDescription" class="java.lang.Object"/>`

Comment: @Alex K, 1. the same exception for "getUserName()" 2) `$P{caseDescription}.getUserName()` is answer for my question (I have incorrect bracets in my jrxml for method call). Could you pass this comment about bracets as answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should thinking about *JasperReports*'s parameter like about a *Java* object.

You need to call method of the object (class). In your case you need to call public getter *`CaseDescription.getUserName()`*.

You can change the expression like this:

```
<textField>
    <reportElement x="0" y="30" width="451" height="29"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Accused : " + $P{caseDescription}.getUserName()]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

or like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" ...>
...
    <import value="your.package.name.CaseDescription"/>
...
    <parameter name="caseDescription" class="java.lang.Object"/>
...
    <textField>
        <reportElement x="0" y="30" width="451" height="29"/>
        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Accused : " + ((CaseDescription) $P{caseDescription}).getUserName()]]></textFieldExpression>
    </textField>
...
</jasperReport>
```

---

<sup>Note:</sup>

To be able use the simple name (not the  fully qualified) of class you need to add `<import value="your.package.name.CaseDescription"/>` at *jrxml* file.